# Unable to understand ImageCaptureConfig.Builder()

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I am trying to implement CameraX using Java. I don't understand why they have used statements like [this](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture#combine-use-cases).

```
new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().build();
new PreviewConfig.Builder().build();
```

Whenever I try to implement, it shows compile error and Builder class remains in red color.

Compile Error:

```
reference to 'Builder' is ambigious, both 'androidx.camera.core.impl.UseCaseConfig.Builder' and 'androidx.camera.core.impl.ImageOutputConfig.Builder'
```

Import:

```
import androidx.camera.core.impl.ImageCaptureConfig;
```

I did not find any inner class 'Builder' in ImageCaptureConfig.java file. However,
 Builder is used in interface UseCaseConfig.java and ImageOutputConfig.java which has been implemented by ImageCaptureConfig.java. How do I implement Builder here and avoid the error of ambiguity?

I have used the latest dependencies and instructions from the [developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture). I am not getting where I am wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the latest camerax core dependency, which is alpha09, you shouldn't use the use case config classes to configure and instantiate use case instances. Unfortunately the documentation wasn't updated to reflect this change.

For example, in order to build a Preview use case, you'd write:

```
Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
```

You can of course configure the preview as you want by calling the Builder setter methods.